# ExtJS 7 Froala editor styles missed in the production build

Tags: extjs, froala

I am using ExtJS 7.2, modern toolkit and want to add a Froala editor as a component to one of my UIs.

With the development build all works just fine, but in a production build some styles are missed. For example `x-froala` class styles from `/node_modules/@sencha/ext-froala-editor/sass/src/froala/Editor.scss` are missed.

`sencha app build -c production` build without errors.

I can add styles manually, bit it doesnt seems the right way for me. Am I missed something?

Comment: did you try `sencha app refresh` after adding flora package?

Comment: @pvlt Thanks for the tip, it didn't help